# SAP Hana Vora : Unable create vora table on cloudera

Tags: vora

I am trying to create a vora table using Spark-Vora but unable to create it. Please find below full error log

```
com.sap.spark.vora.CatalogException$SystemErrorException: System error 
at com.sap.spark.vora.catalog.VoraCatalog.exists(VoraCatalog.scala:122) 
at com.sap.spark.vora.SchemaCatalog.load(SchemaCatalog.java:463) 
at com.sap.spark.vora.SchemaCatalog.loadTable(SchemaCatalog.java:454) 
at com.sap.spark.vora.SchemaCatalog.loadTable(SchemaCatalog.java:122) 
at com.sap.spark.vora.client.catalog.VoraCatalogClient$class.getTableMetadata(VoraCatalogClient.scala:180) 
at com.sap.spark.vora.client.VoraClient.getTableMetadata(VoraClient.scala:58) 
at com.sap.spark.vora.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:165) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CreateTableUsingTemporaryAwareCommand.resolveDataSource(CreateTableUsingTemporaryAwareCommand.scala:73) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CreateTableUsingTemporaryAwareCommand.run(CreateTableUsingTemporaryAwareCommand.scala:31) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:69) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138) 
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:933) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:933) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:144) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:129) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:51) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:725) 
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:30) 
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:35) 
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:37) 
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39) 
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:41) 
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43) 
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:45) 
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47) 
at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:49) 
at $iwC.<init>(<console>:51) 
at <init>(<console>:53) 
at .<init>(<console>:57) 
at .<clinit>(<console>) 
at .<init>(<console>:7) 
at .<clinit>(<console>) 
at $print(<console>) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:674)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused by: com.sap.hl.catalog.VoraCatalogException$ConnectionTimeoutException: Failure in connecting to the catalog within 2 SECONDS
at com.sap.hl.catalog.commands.Utils.handleResult(Utils.java:82)
at com.sap.hl.catalog.commands.Utils.getTransaction(Utils.java:26)
at com.sap.hl.catalog.commands.Exists.call(Exists.java:24)
at com.sap.hl.catalog.commands.Exists.call(Exists.java:10)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)   
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks, 
Akash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that the Vora Catalog is either not installed or not running correctly.

Since the Vora Catalog relies on the Vora DLog, the DLog also needs to be installed and running. For install instructions see [Vora Installation and Administration Guide](http://help.sap.com/Download/Multimedia/hana_vora/SAP_HANA_Vora_Installation_Admin_Guide_en.pdf).
You can check the Vora Discovery Server UI (:8500/ui) for a 'green' entry for 'vora-catalog' and 'dlog'. In case of issues, you can check the log files /var/log/vora-catalog and /var/log/vora-dlog.

Comment: Thanks Frank.  I have checked Vora Discovery Server UI and found 'Red' entry for dlog as well as for vora-catalog but didn't find anything in the log files of dlog and vora-catalog. Do you have any trick to find the issue whereas i followed the same way which mentioned in Vora Installation and Administration Guide.

Comment: You mean you didn't find any logs or you mean you didn't find anything in the logs? What did you find in the logs? I have seen cases where no log files where produced when the wrong network interface was used. Do you have eth0 as network interface in your cluster? If not you need to specify a different network interface in the config for Discovery server, Catalog, and DLog.

Comment: I got a new issue when trying to create a vora table. 


com.sap.spark.vora.CatalogException$SystemErrorException: System error
        at com.sap.spark.vora.catalog.VoraCatalog.store(VoraCatalog.scala:33)
        at com.sap.spark.vora.SchemaCatalog.createTable(SchemaCatalog.java:106)
        at com.sap.spark.vora.client.catalog.VoraCatalogClient$class.createTableInCatalog(VoraCatalogClient.scala:58)
        at com.sap.spark.vora.client.VoraClient.createTableInCatalog(VoraClient.scala:58)

Comment: at com.sap.spark.vora.client.VoraClient$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(VoraClient.scala:331)
        at com.sap.spark.vora.client.VoraClient$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(VoraClient.scala:330)
        at com.sap.spark.vora.client.VoraClient$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(VoraClient.scala:330)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

Comment: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: com.sap.hl.catalog.VoraCatalogException$InternalCatalogError: internal error in catalog (error code: 1)
        at com.sap.hl.catalog.commands.Utils.handleResult(Utils.java:84)
        at com.sap.hl.catalog.commands.Utils.commitTransaction(Utils.java:54)
        at com.sap.hl.catalog.commands.CreateRecursive.call(CreateRecursive.java:37)
        at

Comment: com.sap.spark.vora.CatalogException$SystemErrorException: System error at com.sap.spark.vora.catalog.VoraCatalog.store(VoraCatalog.scala:33)
 at com.sap.spark.vora.SchemaCatalog.createTable(SchemaCatalog.java:106) at com.sap.spark.vora.client.catalog.VoraCatalogClient$class.createTableInCatalog(VoraCatalogClient.scala:58)

Comment: at com.sap.spark.vora.client.VoraClient.createTableInCatalog(VoraClient.scala:58)
        at com.sap.spark.vora.client.VoraClient$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(VoraClient.scala:331)
        at com.sap.spark.vora.client.VoraClient$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(VoraClient.scala:330)
        at com.sap.spark.vora.client.VoraClient$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(VoraClient.scala:330)

Comment: Please open a SAP customer message in HAN-VO for detailed investigation of the installation issues.